# How do I make a different recurring color for each table within the three tabs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I have three tabs. Each tab has a table. Each one of these tables within the tabs has a light blue color reoccurring in the table background. I want each table to have a different reoccurring color in the background. So each tab will have a table with a different background reoccurring color.

- I want tab-1 to have a table with reoccurring color 1
- tab-2 to have a table with reoccurring color 2
- tab-3 to have a table with reoccurring color 3

So each tab has a table within it with a reoccurring background color that is different.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/4zLkb6v0/

```
 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(197, 232, 255, .2);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you care to add a class or ID to your tabs or tables, you'd need to reference each table by tab index. Since `nth-child` pseudo-selectors don't work for class-based selectors, you'll need to select the child divs of your tabs:

```
.tabs > div:nth-child(2) table tr td {
  color: red;
}
```

You can then do zebra-stripes as you like:

```
.tabs > div:nth-child(2) table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  color: blue;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4zLkb6v0/9)**

Answer (score 2):

I added the following css to your fiddle:

```
.tabs .tab:nth-of-type(1) tr {
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  }
.tabs .tab:nth-of-type(2) tr {
  background-color: #00cc00;
  }
.tabs .tab:nth-of-type(3) tr {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4zLkb6v0/10/)**

This allows you to customize the background color of each table separately on each tab, as per your request.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery as an alternative way to achieve that.

```js
$('table').each(function(i,v){
var redStep = parseInt(128/$('table').length);
var greenStep = parseInt(64/$('table').length);
$(v).find('tr:nth-child(even)').css('background-color','rgb('+(128+i*redStep)+', '+(192+i*greenStep)+', 255)')
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.tabs:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.tabs .tab {
  display: inline;
}

.tabs .tab-label {
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 1.00);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  left: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tabs .tab > [type="radio"] {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 1px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tabs .tab-panel {
  display: inline;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.tabs .tab-content {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked + .tab-label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked ~ .tab-panel {
  display: inline;
}


/*=======================================INTERNET EXPLORER 8 and below =======================================*/

@media \0screen\,
screen\9 {
  /* IE7 and IE6 */
  .tabs {
    zoom: 1;
  }
  /* IE8 and below */
  .tabs .tab .tab-radio {
    filter: Alpha(opacity=0);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  /* IE7 and IE6 */
  .tabs .tab .tab-panel,
  {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
  }
  /* IE7 and IE6 */
  .tabs .tab-content,
  {
    float: none;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    width: auto;
  }
  /* IE8 and below */
  .tabs .checked label {
    background: white;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  /* IE8 */
  .tabs .checked .tab-panel {
    display: inline;
  }
  /* IE7 and IE6 */
  .tabs .checked .tab-panel,
  {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/*=======================================UNIMPORTANT STYLES BEGIN HERE=======================================*/

.tabs a:link,
.tabs a:visited,
.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a:focus,
.tabs a:active {
  color: #36A;
}

code,
pre {
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', monospace;
}

pre {
  background: #191919;
  color: #8DA;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

p > code {
  background: #DED;
  margin: -2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.for {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.for:after {
  background: #DDD;
  bottom: 150%;
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.for:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.for.default-tab {
  color: #8AD;
}

.for.ie8-and-below {
  color: #DA8;
}

.for.default-tab:after {
  content: 'For default tab';
}

.for.ie8-and-below:after {
  content: 'For IE8 and below';
}


/* and just for fun... */

@media only screen and (max-width: 43em) {
  .tabs .tab > label {
    background: #BBB;
    border-color: #999;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked + .tab-label {
    background: #222;
    border-color: #444;
    color: #DDD;
  }
}

.name {
  min-width: 350px !important;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 6px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}

.right-image {
  /*background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top right;
        background-image: url("~/Content/Images/Untitled-1.png");
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(167,218,255,0.20),white );
        background-image: url("~/content/images/Untitled-1.png");*/
  width: 510px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.tabs a {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  display: inline;
}

.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a.active {
  background: #666;
  color: black;
}

.tabContent {
  border: 1px solid #4cff00;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 500px;
}

#day2 {
  margin-top: -24px;
}

#day3 {
  margin-top: -48px;
}

.center-image {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .3;
  width: 90%;
  left: 170px;
  top: -75px;
  z-index: 10;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}

.text-glow {
  /*text-shadow: -3px 0px 10px #FFF, 3px 0px 10px #FFF, 0px 0px 10px #FFF, -3px -3px 10px #FFF, 3px -3px 10px #FFF, 0px -3px 10px #FFF, -3px 3px 10px #FFF, 3px 3px 10px #FFF, 0px 3px 10px #FFF;
        */
  z-index: 20;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

.main2 {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 97%;
  border: 0px solid #ddd;
  margin: 25px;
}

th,
td {
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(130, 232, 255, .2);
}

.font {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.font:hover,
.font:active,
.font:focus,
.font:visited,
.font:link,
.font:target,
:target {
  color: rgba(255, 117, 0, 1.00);
}

.font2 {
  color: rgba(255, 117, 0, 1.00);
}

.tabs2 {
  background: rgba(255, 86, 0, 1.00);
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.name {
  min-width: 350px !important;
}

.right-image {
  /*background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top right;
        background-image: url("~/Content/Images/Untitled-1.png");
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(167,218,255,0.20),white );
        background-image: url("~/content/images/Untitled-1.png");*/
  width: 510px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.tabs {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.tabs a {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  display: inline;
}

.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a.active {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabContent {
  border: 1px solid #4cff00;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 500px;
}

.center-image {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1.0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0px;
  top: -10px;
  /*  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
        background-image: url("~/Content/Images/banner3.png")no-repeat;*/
}

.center-image > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-glow {
  /*text-shadow: -3px 0px 10px #FFF, 3px 0px 10px #FFF, 0px 0px 10px #FFF, -3px -3px 10px #FFF, 3px -3px 10px #FFF, 0px -3px 10px #FFF, -3px 3px 10px #FFF, 3px 3px 10px #FFF, 0px 3px 10px #FFF;
        */
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked="">
    <label class="tab-label" for="tab-1"> <b class="font">Day 1 - July 19, 2016</b></label>
    <div class="tab-panel">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="name">Course Name</th>
              <th>Course Description</th>
              <th>Presenter(s)</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>New MyPerformance Automated Tool: First You Need the Tool</td>
<td>New MyPerformance Automated Tool: First You Need the Tool</td>
<td>New MyPerformance Automated Tool: First You Need the Tool</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
    <label class="tab-label" for="tab-2">
      <b class="font">Day 2 - July 20, 2016</b>
    </label>
    <div class="tab-panel">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="name">Course Name</th>
              <th>Course Description</th>
              <th>Presenter(s)</th>
            </tr>


            <tr>
              <td>Basic Health and Life Insurance Programs: Throw me a Lifeline</td>
<td>Basic Health and Life Insurance Programs: Throw me a Lifeline</td>
<td>Basic Health and Life Insurance Programs: Throw me a Lifeline</td>
</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
    <label class="tab-label" for="tab-3"> <b class="font">Day 3 - July 21, 2016</b></label>
    <div class="tab-panel">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="name">Course Name</th>
              <th>Course Description</th>
              <th>Presenter(s)</th>
            </tr>

 <tr>
              <td>Basic Health and Life Insurance Programs: Throw me a Lifeline</td>
<td>Basic Health and Life Insurance Programs: Throw me a Lifeline</td>
<td>Basic Health and Life Insurance Programs: Throw me a Lifeline</td>
</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```